# Cassandra query on 2 dates

Tags: cassandra, apache-spark

Can we run a query like...

```
Date1 BETWEEN (range1, range2) AND Date2 BETWEEN(range3, range4)
```

From what I gather this is not Cassandra's Forte.

Can it be achieved with Spark SQL and Cassandra?

Answer (score 4):

In cassandra range query can be performed only on clustering key. So If you have a schema where DATE1 is clustering key you can do range query.

eg:

```
 CREATE TABLE foo_table (
 userid text,
 period timestamp,
 data text,
 PRIMARY KEY((customer),period)
```

);

`select * from foo_table where userid='user1' and period >= '2000-01-10'`

Comment: So if we have multiple timestamps fields that represent different types of dates it's not the best solution? Or basically create different table for the same data but keyed with each one of those date fields